# Working with breeze.js and multi data sources

Tags: breeze

I'm trying to integrate breeze.js on my SPA . 
Working with in with the entity structure comming from the DB is really straightforward.
I have a problem when I need to deal with special cases. Here is my case :
I need to get my entity list , in the first time I fill the entity from external source only for display mode (the original data exists in an external source) , when I see the data then I can choose which to approve, then I'll save the entities in my DB.

Do you know to manage this with breeze in automatic way .

Thank in advance ...

Comment: Automatic is such an out of text term here...  Create a data layer that intercepts the save calls and 'manually' set it up from there.  Nothing will be automatic, I don't think, or it would have tied Breeze to a tech stack.

Comment: I agree with PW Kad on this regarding "automatic" .  What you can do is retrieve data from any external source and as long as you hydrate into "known" entity types on the client, you can then persist that data anywhere that understands these types. Not sure how clear this is but ...

Comment: Ok, Thanks . I meant by automatic way , when I return the entities filed from the external source to the client , then make changes , the save changes of breeze will not help me because these entities were not tracked by the breeze context .

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the NoDB sample in the Breeze zip.